# Elasticsearch custom query for getting elements of particular range?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch so, here is my doubt:

`I have large data inserted into Elastic search. The data that I have inserted contains an attribute of marks of each subject, is it possible to write an Elasticsearch query to find the number of students who has their marks in the inputted range.`

**Example:**

```
|studentname | maths | computers |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|s1          |78     |90         |
==================================
|s2          |56     |75         |
==================================
|s3          |45     |50         |
==================================
```

Assuming the data that is present in the ES in a tabular manner, is it possible to

> 1.Find the list of students who has scored more than 50 marks in computers.
>
> 2.Find the list of students who has scored more than 60 marks in both subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use range query :-

```
{  
   "query":{"bool":{"must":{"range":{computers:{gte: 50} }}}}
}
```

Check this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)

Comment: can you be a bit more elaborate? About method type and URL request ?

Comment: Here computer type should be long or integer .URL -  index/type/_search

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: do you have any idea how to make this request in java? or where can I go and read about it?

Comment: Check this link ,https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.4/java-range.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141552/discussion-between-abhishek-ekaanth-and-vijay-gupta).

Comment: Sure . we will chat  .